# Does this photodiode need an operational amplifier?

Tags: arduino, photodiode, 5v

I'm trying to make a circuit for a pulse watch, which should be capable of measuring blood SpO2. I use 2 LEDs for each wavelength (respectively [660nm](https://dk.farnell.com/vishay/tsal6400/ir-emitter-940nm-5mm-through-hole/dp/3152868) and [940nm](https://dk.farnell.com/vishay/tsal6400/ir-emitter-940nm-5mm-through-hole/dp/3152868)) to shine at the upper wrist. 
The reflected light is supposed to be picked up by the following photodiode: 
https://dk.farnell.com/hamamatsu/s1223/photodiode-pin-to-5/dp/1495587

Everything should be wired to my Arduino and the supplied voltage is 5V.

Below you can see the circuit:

[image: Circuit]

Do you think I will need any operational amplifier for this photodiode? - In the case of yes, since I'm new to this, which one would you recommend?

Comment: That’s a design question. Please show us your insights to define the signal conditioning for the Arduino interface. What’s your question against the design?

Comment: Oh i see! Well its just an Arduino UNO. Each of the LEDs are placed roughly 0.5cm away from the sensor - was that what you were looking for?

Comment: It all depends on how much reflected light is received and what filtering on the signal you are intending to apply and the resolution of your ADC.

Comment: You have to realize that the photodiode will react to **all** light. If there's too much unwanted light falling onto the photodiode the light from the LEDs might become insignificant compared to that unwanted light. The signal on V_out might become **very** small, smaller than what the ADC in an Arduino can reliably measure. It is hard to say "do this and it will be fine" because **it depends**. You might want to look at similar designs and see what circuit is used there right after the photodiode.

Comment: I really don't plan to filter the signal. I guess I will handle that in software (I'm programming a mobile application around it) 
- I have no clue how much light will be reflected, but I've read some scientific articles about this, and they don't utilize any op-amps, even though they have 1 less LED and less intensity.  
That's partly the reason why I choose to go with 2 LEDs for each nm.

Comment: "I have no clue how much light will be reflected" - Not to be rude, but if you don't know how much light the PD will get, how do you expect us to tell you whether you need an op amp to handle that unknown signal? Hint - the answer is probably yes, but that's just because it almost always is. And your blind faith that you will be able to deal with problems in software is quite likely to get you in deep trouble somewhere down the line. Just because you are comfortable with software does not mean that it's a universal panacea. Start learning about the hardware.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast 
1. If I knew about the hardware, I wouldn't be here
2. How on earth, do you expect me to know how much light the PD will get?? Tissue and skin thickness varies from human to human, meaning that the reflected light will vary too (A LOT). 
3. If you fully knew the application of this device, I welcome you to comment on whether software signal processing is ok or not.. but in this case, you simply don't know. 

Lastly, I picked a PD with a high spectral response, and I thought that you would be able to tell whether an OP-AMP would be necessary or not based on my information.

Comment: "How on earth, do you expect me to know how much light the PD will get?? Tissue and skin thickness varies from human to human, meaning that the reflected light will vary too (A LOT)" - If you don't know, experiment. Once you have a result, you can ask reasonable questions. This is not like writing software, where you can tell in advance what you need. If your Google-fu is good, there is almost certainly a paper somewhere on the web which discusses exactly this issue, but you need to accept that you're going to have to actually build stuff and discard it when it doesn't work.

Comment: " If you fully knew the application of this device, I welcome you to comment on whether software signal processing is ok or not.. but in this case, you simply don't know. " Exactly. Which is why I responded as I did. I don't know, you don't know, nobody knows - so no declarative  response is possible. Please note that I did give a general answer. You probably need an op amp. Beyond that, until you get some real data we're both whistling in the dark - and I just wanted you to be aware that you are part of the orchestra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can consider the following:

A transimpedance amplifier (using an opamp) is used for

- Higher speeds - If the photodiode has a significant capacitance.
- Higher amplification - You may get into trouble with biasing otherwise.
- Better linearity - The photodiode biasing voltage is more constant.
- Low output impedance - The opamp also acts as a buffer.

Just the regular resistor biasing can be used for

- Lowest power consumption - Only a single branch with current (usually negligible).
- Lower noise - No added noise by the opamp + possible compensation capacitor.
- Simplicity - No need to look at stability or choosing a suitable opamp.

My advice is to keep a transimpedance amplifier in mind. When used correctly it almost always leads to a better performance. If you're designing a PCB for example, you can always choose not to mount the opamp if it is not necessary.